# Python - looping

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, goto

I am trying to build a simple calculator. I just want the user to enter two numbers and an operation, then for the calculation to be shown, then to loop back to entering two numbers again. If the user enters an operation that is not recognized I want to loop back to 'enter operation'.

Why is this not working:

```
def add (a,b):
    return a + b

def minus (a,b):
    return a - b

def multi (a,b):
    return a * b 

def div (a,b):
    return a / b

def numPic():
    num1 = int(input("Type a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Type another number: "))

def opPic():
        op = input("Type an operation (add,minus,multi,div):" )
        if op == "add":
          print (add (num1,num2))
        elif (op == "minus"):
          print (minus(num1,num2))
        elif (op == "multi"):
          print (mulit(num1,num2))
        elif (op == "div"):
          print (div(num1,num2))
        else :
          print ("operation not recognised") 
          opPic ()

print ("Hello User")
numPic()
opPic()
```

Comment: You are not using loop.

Comment: You have no loops in your code. I assume you're getting `NameError`s trying to access `num1` and `num2`?

Comment: It looks like you've got a school assignment that you want us to solve. The problem is quite obvious and you've even tagged the question with `while-loop` without using a while loop. Please google `python while loop` and give us the code you've tried to get it to work and we can push you in the right direction. a hint tho: `while: numPic()`

Comment: Slightly off question but if this is python 2, you should use `raw_input` not `input`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few bugs.  First, `num1` and `num2` are local to `numPic`--not
global.  So you need to return them to the caller, and the caller has to pass
them to `opPic()`:

```
def numPic():
    num1 = int(input("Type a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Type another number: "))
    return num1, num2

def opPic(num1, num2):
    op = input("Type an operation (add,minus,multi,div):" )
    if op == "add":
      print (add (num1,num2))
    elif (op == "minus"):
      print (minus(num1,num2))
    elif (op == "multi"):
      print (mulit(num1,num2))
    elif (op == "div"):
      print (div(num1,num2))
    else :
      print ("operation not recognised") 
      opPic (num1, num2)

num1, num2 = numPic()
opPic (num1, num2)
```

To make it loop-based, you could do something like:

```
def opPic(num1, num2):
    while True:
      op = input("Type an operation (add,minus,multi,div):" )
      if op == "add":
        print (add (num1,num2))
      elif (op == "minus"):
        print (minus(num1,num2))
      elif (op == "multi"):
        print (mulit(num1,num2))
      elif (op == "div"):
        print (div(num1,num2))
      else :
        print ("operation not recognised") 
        continue

      break
```

Hopefully, you can figure out the other bit on your own, as this looks like a school assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The `num1` and `num2` you define in `numPic` are local to that function. You need to return them and pass them to the `opPic` function for them to be used.

```
def numPic():
    num1 = int(input("Type a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Type another number: "))
    return num1, num2

def opPic(num1, num2):
    #the same code as before
    #except changing opPic() to opPic(num1, num2)

print ("Hello User")
num1, num2 = numPic()
opPic(num1, num2)
```

There are better ways of doing what you seem to be aiming for though. You haven't actually used a loop and have used recursion instead.

Comment: Just to point out, this is a bug in the code, not the answer for his/her question.

Comment: @WoozyCoder, The question was "why is this not working?" Admittedly it's not how I'd have solved the problem but still.

Comment: YES! This works, but as you have pointed out it seems as though I am achieving this in a unorthodox way.